# How to compute vectors with walls restricting resultant directions.

Tags: vectors

I am working on a problem where I need vectors not at $180$ degrees to act as if they were. I figured I could accomplish this with walls. For example say two people play tug of war on the corner of a building, they would be at $90$ degrees but their vectors would cancel as if they were $180$ degrees apart. I was wondering how this could be extended to n people playing "tug of war" with $n$ walls restricting the resultants vectors so that a resultant vector could only be in the direction one of the initial vectors were pointing.

Comment: I imagine that "tug of war" is a game. But you can imagine that in the remote very inland place of the planet where I live, nobody has ever heard of it. Thus, could you give a reference where I can get acquainted with the rules of this game ?

Comment: Sorry yah, so imagine two people pulling a rope on opposite sides. Whoever pulls the rope past a given distance wins. If you imagine this game played by vectors 180 degrees apart then the direction the resultant vector points to is the winner and the magnitude is how much he won by.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Comment: no problem hope I made it more clear